# Generating Fibonacci sequence with PL/pgSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I'm trying to generate the Fibonacci sequence with a function in SQL. It takes an input parameter `pstop integer` (10 by default) and returns a table with all Fibonacci numbers less than `pstop`.

But the output starts with these numbers (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13) and skips the numbers of the beginning of the sequence which are 0 and 1 (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13).
How can I fix it?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_fibonacci (pstop INTEGER DEFAULT 10)
RETURNS TABLE (fibonacci_num INTEGER) AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    a INTEGER;
    b INTEGER;
    c INTEGER;
BEGIN
    a := 0;
    b := 1;
    fibonacci_num := 0;
    WHILE
        fibonacci_num < pstop LOOP
        c := a + b;
        fibonacci_num := c;
        IF
            fibonacci_num < pstop THEN
            RETURN NEXT;
        END IF;
        a := b;
        b := c;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT * FROM fnc_fibonacci(20);
```

Comment: Insert another `RETURN NEXT;` after `fibonacci_num := 0;`? As an aside, you can do it in pure SQL, see [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/recursive-queries-postgresql/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To note: the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) starts with ***0, 1, 1, 2*** (not *0, 1, 2*).

Assignments are ever so slightly expensive in PL/pgSQL. So keep those at a minimum. It's an academic consideration for a function returning no more than 46 rows with type `integer`. (It gets more relevant with *big* numbers operating with `numeric`.)

Anyway, here is an optimized function with a **single addition and assignment** per output row:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_fibonacci (pstop int = 10)
  RETURNS SETOF int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$func$
DECLARE
    a int := 0;
    b int := 1;
BEGIN
   /*
   -- optional sanity check:
   -- function starts operating at 2
   -- and int4 computation overflows past Fibonacci Nr. 1836311903
   IF pstop NOT BETWEEN 2 AND 1836311903 THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Pass integer betwen 2 and 1836311903. Received %', pstop;
   END IF;
   */

   -- main
   RETURN NEXT 0;
   RETURN NEXT 1;
   LOOP
      a := a + b;
      EXIT WHEN a >= pstop;
      RETURN NEXT a;

      b := b + a;
      EXIT WHEN b >= pstop;
      RETURN NEXT b;
   END LOOP;
END;
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cxCVxwJV)

Note that we can simply `RETURN NEXT 0;` in a function declared with `RETURNS SETOF int` without naming any `OUT` parameters. (Column names in `RETURNS TABLE` are `OUT` parameters, too.)
Details in the manual chapter [*"Returning from a Function"*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_fibonacci (pstop INTEGER DEFAULT 10) 
RETURNS TABLE (fibonacci_num INTEGER)
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    a INTEGER;
    b INTEGER;
    c INTEGER;
BEGIN
    a := 0;
    b := 1;
    fibonacci_num := 0;
    RETURN NEXT;

    fibonacci_num := 1;
    RETURN NEXT;
    
    WHILE fibonacci_num < pstop LOOP 
        c := a + b;
        fibonacci_num := c;
        IF fibonacci_num < pstop THEN
            RETURN NEXT;
        END IF;
        a := b;
        b := c;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT * FROM fnc_fibonacci(20);
```